# Ant crawling between opposite corners on a cubical box

Tags: geometry, puzzle, solid-geometry

> Consider a cubical box with $1\,\mathrm{m}$ side-length which has one corner placed at $(0,0,0)$ and the opposite corner placed at $(1,1,1)$. What is the shortest distance that an ant crawling from the point $(0,0,0)$ to the point $(1,1,1)$ must travel?
>
> $$\text{(a)}\;\sqrt{6}\qquad \text{(b)}\;\sqrt{5}\qquad \text{(c)}\;2\sqrt{3}\qquad \text{(d)}\;1+\sqrt{3} $$

If we think mathematically, then the ant could first crawl along the height of the box to travel a distance of $1\,\mathrm{m}$, and then move  diagonally along the upper side/face of the box traveling $\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{m}$ more. So the total distance it travels is $1+\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{m}$, but this answer doesn't match any of the options.

---

I was confused  where to post the problem: either this site or [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). I found a [similar problem there](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22865/ant-on-a-hyperbox), but since this puzzle has some mathematical content I decided to post it here.

Comment: Hint. Think as if it is a straight path instead of on a cube.(Put two side of cube in one dimension)

Comment: Further hint: Remove the top, and then flatten the box. In the flattened version, a shortest path is obvious.

Comment: Did you mean like these image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wc9gi.png

Comment: @SAHEBPAL The path in the image you posted does not go from one corner of the cube to the opposite corner. Rather, the goes from corner to a corner that is one edge removed from it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A shortest path (actually, due to symmetries, one of many equivalent shortest paths) is
$$(0,0,0) \to (1/2,0,1)\to(1,1,1).$$

[image]

It's a diagonal of the $1\times 2$ rectangle (bent into two squares), hence its length is $\sqrt{1^2+2^2} = \sqrt 5.$

Comment: Can you explain in details or adding some picture to help in understanding.

Comment: @SAHEBPAL Sure :)

Comment: Yes. I got it. Also please provide me some another  equivalent shortest paths. @CiaPan

Comment: @SAHEBPAL Try any two sides adjacent to one another, with one being adjacent to the starting vertex, and the other one adjacent to the end vertex. (There are six such pairs.)

Comment: Yeah.. Such as $(0,0,0) \to (0,1/2,1)\to(1,1,1)$.